# Nested Object Keyname as variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

iam trying to set a variable as a keyname but as always iam just failing. (javascript newbie)

Here is my example object:

```
disk = {
    "id": {
        "type": "xxxx",
        "content": "xxxx"
    }
}
```

Later i want to output my content with disk[id].content. Now the question is how to set the key 'id' with an variable? (got a unique id with i try to get in there)

In the end it should read: (for example)
    disk = {
        "5546": {
            "type": "xxxx",
            "content": "xxxx"
        }
    }

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use variables for key names using object literal notation.

You need to use `disk = {}; disk[id] = { content: ..., type: ... }`.

Comment: Wohoo thats all i wanted, thanks a lot. :) Just got the wrong syntax.

Answer (score 2):

So you want:

```
var id = "5546";
var disk = {
    id: {/*etc*/}
}
```

And expect:

```
disk: { 5546: {/*etc*/} }
```

You *can't* do this in JavaScript with this notation.

You *can* do:

```
var id = "5549";
var disk = {};
disk[id] = {/*etc*/};
```